# Extending Grid Panel in Sencha Architect

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect, gridpanel

I want to write my own Grid panel by extending the native grid panel provided by Sencha in Sencha Architect. i am new to sencha architect. Can some one help in providing the steps to do that ?

Comment: Those who are reducing the rating of question, please add the comment why is that done??? Cant we ask a basic question in Stack overflow?? only geniuses are allowed to ask question????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with you. They just reduce the raiting but don't post any answer.

I'm not any sencha extjs expert but I think you can create a new class in Project Inspector -> + icon -> class and so set the extended class.